# How to delete carriage returns from Nano?

Tags: nano, windows-subsystem-for-linux, crossplatform

I copied something from Windows to Nano in [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and it included carriage returns (CR characters). Even though I removed all carriage returns with the text editor (Notepad++) these are still added after copying, possibly by Windows itself - The more the window is narrower, the more carriage returns Windows adds.

[image]

### My question:

How could I remove all carriage returns in a find and replace (`CTRL+\`) action in Nano?

### Update1:

If I paste the script and just saving (CTRL+O) there is no change (I made sure that when saving, dos mode is toggled off).

### Update2:

Executing `dos2unix` on the file didn't help - it still contains these Green boxes and as for now I can remove them only manually (not a solution of course). I know there are carriage returns, because if I copy the file back to Notepad++, I see these are displayed as CR chars, when I do `View > Show symbol > Show all characters`.

Comment: Why in nano? `sed 's/\r//' ses.sh > ses2.sh`  from command line.

Comment: Refer to [Remove carriage return in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/800030/4518341)

Comment: nano seems to automatically remove them. If I open a file that contains them and then ^O, it's saved without the carriage returns

Comment: can you search for `\r` and replace with nothing?

Comment: Windows uses CR+LF line endings and drops CR on text mode on load and re-adds them on save. *nix has no such concept. However, Windows `notepad.exe` opens text files in binary mode and expects CR+LF line endings. LF line endings will be invisible on `notepad.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems not to be necessary.

```
$ echo -e 'foo\rbar\r\n' > nano
$ cat -A nano
foo^Mbar^M$
$
$ nano nano
```

[image]

I do absolutely nothing except type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to save the file, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit...

```
$ cat -A nano
foo$
bar$
$
```

So apparently simply opening a file and saving it in `nano` on Ubuntu is sufficient to destroy carriage returns.

Comment: I don't know about WSL, but in nano 2.6.3 on my xenial box **when the line endings are CRLF** rather than just CR, it seems to require an extra step of hitting Ctrl-D in the save dialog to toggle DOS format **off**

Comment: Thanks Zanna! Till now the only thing I did (both in WSL and in a remote machine I tunneled into **from** WSL) was just CTRL+X because as far as I know, it encapsulates CTRL+O. @steeldriver do you suggest the sequence CTRL+O, CTRL+D, CTRL+X?

Comment: ^X alone allows me to exit without prompting me - seems to be a special case in that respect @Benia

Comment: If the buffer is unmodified it will, but if any change was made, usually it will prompt...

Comment: yes I know, that's why I'm saying this is a special case, because ^X lets me exit and the file is unchanged, but ^O modifies the file (even though I haven't done anything) @Benia

Comment: Oh I now understand you.

Answer (score 2):

The green cell is not *carriage return* but *trailing whitespace*, which is defined in `/usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc` like this:

```
# Trailing whitespace.
color ,green "[[:space:]]+$"
```

Thus, can be removed by replacing the regex `[[:space:]]+$` or `\s+$` or  `+$` with "nothing" by doing the following inside `nano`:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to open the "search and replace" prompt.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to enable RegEx search.
3. Enter `[[:space:]]+$` or `\s+$` or  `+$` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to search for trailing whitespace.
4. Press `Enter` to replace the found whitespace with "nothing".
5. Enter `A` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply to all occurences of whitespace.